# Pulse Detection

Tags: led, driver

I have the following simple LED driver.

[image]

I over drive LED much beyond its current limits in terms of current. (50mA @ 25% duty cycle with an RMS current around 12mA). In this case the circuit doesn't violate any safety requirements.

Recently, I had to send this circuit for some safety test. During the safety test the operator shorts DS as a fault condition and RMS value of the current increase to 50mA which violates the safety requirements. I like to modify this circuit in a way that it is able to gracefully fail in fault conditions. Especially around the driver Mosfet.

One idea I had was to sense the pulse and take action (cut power to LED) if there is no pulse. Again, I thought of using a valley detector driving another mosfet which controls the power to the LED. But this looks complicated.

I am looking for a simple novel solution that would cut the power to the LED if there is no pulse.

Comment: Have you tried a polyfuse yet?

Comment: @ignacio they don't make it at the rating I need. The smallest one is 120mA I need about 70mA.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv682=28&FV=fff4000a%2Cfff80390&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: In your circuit, R1 already limits LED current to less than 30mA if the FET shorts from Drain to Source. Is that what you intended, or is the circuit not accurate?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for the Digikey link. None of them has a trip current of 70mA. The smallest one is 98mA.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I will update the question but essentially think of it this way. When I am pulsing with 30% duty cycle, I pass around 90mA with an RMS value of 30mA. BUt safety operator shorts the DS manually than the 90mA becomes DC and violates the safety requirement. That's why I am trying to detect lack of pulse and shut the system down. The frequency is about 1MHz.

Comment: Three legs of a FET and 300 Ohm :-). Then shorting one will fault less current.

Comment: What's the LED's forward voltage and is there any reason why you can't connect the 100 ohm ballast on the drain side of the MOSFET?

Comment: @EMFields i don't think drain side helps. the person is trying to shut the system down when there is no pwm. drain side resistor has no impact on that objective.

Comment: @jasp: I'm well aware of what the OP wants to do, and I didn't ask whether R1 being on the drain side of the MOSFET "helped", I merely asked whether it being connected there mattered. From your comment, I gather that in your opinion it doesn't. Thanks for that.

Comment: I think that the problem with this question is that the schematic is not consistent with the text. If you have 90 mA flowing through the LED when the MOSFET is on, that means that there must be 9V across the resistor, which in turn means that the power supply must be on the order of 11-12V in order to account for the additional drop across the LED. Also, the gate voltage would also need to be 2-4V higher than the source voltage, which means that you aren't driving the gate directly from a microcontroller. Please edit the text and/or the diagram so that the question is self-consistent.

Comment: Is that test for SW failure or for HW failure? If it is for (a single) HW failure you could put two FETs in series. (But better put the resistor at the drain side). If it for SW failure: what average current is allowed? Maybe you could split the resistor and put an elco at the junction, so one resistor limits the average current and the other the peak.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen hardware failure. Two Fets is a great idea.

Comment: @DaveTweed so true. Apologies for this. I should have done a better job. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be to include an oscillator in the LED circuit.  The output from the microcontroller then turns the oscillator on and off.  It doesn't matter then if the signal is shorted - it will still provide the proper duty cycle.

If your processor is driving the LED at various frequencies then that suggestion won't help.

In that case, use a one shot that can be reset.  The one shot should have a time period longer than the lowest pulse rate you need to generate, but short enough not to burn out the LED.  The one shot needs to be resettable so that it turns off the LED when the processor sends the signal to turn the LED off.

You can use a 555 Timer - data and example schematics all over the web.  Normally a one shot will have the reset pin (pin 4) tied to VCC.  You'll need to invert the signal from your microprocessor and use that to drive the reset pin.  Drive the trigger (pin 2) with your microprocessor signal, and reset (pin 4) with the invers of that.

When your trigger goes low, the 555 triggers its output.  When your trigger goes high, the 555 will reset its output.  If you pull the input low and keep it there, the 555 will trigger its output and then reset it when the timer runs out.

The output is inverted from what you need - triggered is high, reset is low.  You'll either have to invert it or use a different FET to drive your LED.

Given R is the resistor connected from pin 7 to VCC and C is the capacitor from pin 6 to ground then the pulse length in seconds is 1.1*R*C where R in in ohms and C in in Farads.

NOTE:
All of this assumes that your LED driver is an enclosed unit and won't be tested in parts.  If your tester goes in and shorts the FET gate to ground, then nothing will save you except some kind of low power fuse (if there is such a beast.)  If the test point is only where the microprocessor drives the LED driver, then this will work.

This schematic is more or less what I mean (R7 should be 10K:)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLCOE1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could you please help me figure out how I can design a one shot detector?

Comment: Good answer but operator really goes and shorts the FET's legs as a single fault condition.

Answer (score 1):

You might just try a series capacitor between microcontroller and MOSFET gate.  It will pass AC but not DC, thus a sustained high level on the uC pin won't hold the FET on.  Some experimenting with the value might be required.

Comment: good point. However the safety test done with the idea of shorting DS of the fet manually. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a dumb safety test.  In that case I guess I would just pick a high efficiency LED (they make some really bright red ones) and run it at a lower current that would allow continuous operation.

Answer (score 1):

Add a second FET in series. I'm not sure if you can just connect two N-channel FETs in series (DS-DS); if not, you could use a P-channel FET on the high side and drive its gate with an inverted control signal.

The question seems silly to me, but if the objective really is to guard against a single component being shorted, then redundancy is the answer. What if the resistor gets shorted? You'd need to split it into two series resistors. Though shorting one of them would double the current. So it would be better to put the second resistor behind the high-side FET, so that you have a current source → LED → current sink, both limiting to a maximum current.

@Pericynthion's suggestion about a series capacitor between the drive signal and FET gate would also bring extra protection against the signal getting stuck on. Maybe you want to do that as well, but hopefully some finite number of protective circuits will be deemed enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

A schematic follows, and the LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n39fk9j6dc6izs8/1MHz%20LED%20switch.asc?dl=0) if you want to play with the circuit.

[image]